# Can not create ClusterClient using ClientBuilder on Orleans 7.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, orleans

I was able to create a cluster client in Orleans v3.6.0. But now in v7.0 there is not a `Build()` method in the `ClientBuilder` class.

```cs
var client = new ClientBuilder()
   .UseLocalhostClustering()
   .Build(); // gives an error here.
```

I've checked the source code and there is no `Build` method on the`IClientBuilder` interface.

How should I create a ClusterClient in Orleans 7.0?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `HostBuilder.UseOrleansClient()`. It is also described in `whats new in Orleans` in this link: [whats new in Orleans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/whats-new-in-orleans#hosting)

Comment: The documentation seems wrong and needs to be updated here.  Very confusing indeed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/host/client?pivots=orleans-7-0